# Set resultRow variable as ActiveCell

Tags: excel, vba

I am copying tables from a word .docx file into an excel sheet.

My code below works fine, however, my issue is that I want to set my `resultRow` variable to be the `ActiveCell.row` instead of a fixed integer. So that I can paste my table into an active cell rather than a defined cell range. I have tried changing it to `resultRow = ActiveCell` and `Set resultRow = ActiveCell` but they are not working. Any help is appreciated. My code is shown below:

```
Sub ImportWordTable()

Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim tableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel
Dim resultRow As Long
Dim tableStart As Integer
Dim tableTot As Integer

On Error Resume Next

ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ").ClearContents

wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.doc", , _
"Browse for file containing table to be imported")

If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

With wdDoc
    tableNo = wdDoc.Tables.Count
    tableTot = wdDoc.Tables.Count
    If tableNo = 0 Then
        MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
        vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
    ElseIf tableNo > 1 Then
        tableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & tableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
        "Enter the table to start from", "Import Word Table", "1")
    End If

    resultRow = 1

For tableStart = tableNo To tableTot
    .Tables(tableStart).Borders.Enable = True
    .Tables(tableStart).Range.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & resultRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
    resultRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Next
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AZ" & resultRow).UnMerge
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove that `On Error Resume Next`... it's hiding potential errors. Then, your question is a bit unclear... do you want `resultRow = ActiveCell.Row`?

Comment: Oh...i didnt know... okay, thank you! Yes, correct! `ActiveCell.Row` Let me change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User @BigBen above is right, just implement `resultRow = ActiveCell.Row`!
See answer in full below:

```
Sub ImportWordTable()

Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim tableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel
Dim resultRow As Long
Dim tableStart As Integer
Dim tableTot As Integer

On Error Resume Next

ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ").ClearContents

wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.doc", , _
"Browse for file containing table to be imported")

If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

With wdDoc
    tableNo = wdDoc.Tables.Count
    tableTot = wdDoc.Tables.Count
    If tableNo = 0 Then
        MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
        vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
    ElseIf tableNo > 1 Then
        tableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & tableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
        "Enter the table to start from", "Import Word Table", "1")
    End If

    resultRow = 1

For tableStart = tableNo To tableTot
    .Tables(tableStart).Borders.Enable = True
    .Tables(tableStart).Range.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & resultRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
    resultRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Next
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AZ" & resultRow).UnMerge
End With

End Sub
```